# Easiest way to pass a string array to a function that takes only a string and get a string array output

Tags: powershell

So, I have a string array in Powershell:

`$defaultAutoRecover`:

```
%ProgramFiles%\windows defender\clientwmiinstall.mof
%ProgramFiles%\windows defender\protectionmanagement.mof
%windir%\system32\deliveryoptimizationmiprov.mof
%windir%\system32\psmodulediscoveryprovider.mof
%windir%\system32\wbem\appbackgroundtask.mof
%windir%\system32\wbem\bcd.mof
%windir%\system32\wbem\cimdmtf.mof
%windir%\system32\wbem\cimwin32.mof
%windir%\system32\wbem\dmwmibridgeprov.mof
%windir%\system32\wbem\dmwmibridgeprov1.mof
%windir%\system32\wbem\dnsclientpsprovider.mof
```

I want to expand all these environment variables before using this string array.

I've tried:
`([System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($defaultAutoRecover))`

But, all the items get concatenated in to a single string separated by spaces.

Output:
`C:\Program Files\windows defender\clientwmiinstall.mof C:\Program Files\windows defender\protectionmanagement.mof C:\windows\system32\deliveryoptimizationmiprov.mof C:\windows\system32\psmodulediscoveryprovider.mof C:\windows\system32\wbem\appbackgroundtask.mof C:\windows\system32\wbem\bcd.mof C:\windows\system32\wbem\cimdmtf.mof C:\windows\system32\wbem\cimwin32.mof C:\windows\system32\wbem\dmwmibridgeprov.mof C:\windows\system32\wbem\dmwmibridgeprov1.mof C:\windows\system32\wbem\dnsclientpsprovider.mof`

What is the most straight forward way to process this array and end up with an array without building out a multi-line foreach statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enumerate each element and pass it as argument of `ExpandEnvironmentVariables`, you can assign the result of this expression to the same variable (or any variable of your choosing) to have a new array:

```
$defaultAutoRecover = $defaultAutoRecover | ForEach-Object {
    [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($_)
}
```